# datetime from MySQL compared in PHP to show link

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, if-statement, strtotime

Im trying to display a link based on a time difference.

```
if((MySQL_DATE - TODAY) > 2 WEEKS) {
    <a href="http://www.url.com">Link</a>
}
```

But I cant get it to work correctly.

I was using the `strtotime` function but its not working the way im expecting it to:

```
if(((strtotime($hm_datelisted)) - (strtotime('now'))) > (strtotime('2 week'))) {
    <a href="http://www.url.com">Link</a>
}
```

If you use '>' the link doesnt work at all and '<' displays the link permanently

Comment: tip: `strtotime('now')` might as well just be `time()`, with far far less parsing overhead

Answer (score 0):

Look into using MySQL's NOW() function. It is more precise and easier to handle.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to subtract "today".  Today's timestamp is 1348712844.  Two weeks from now is 1349922505.  The sum of these is 2698635588, which is around 2055.  I think you just want to check that `hm_datelisted` is greater than two weeks from now, but I'm not sure what that column contains either.

Comment: ok I think to got it. First I had the first two items around the wrong way: '(strtotime($hm_datelisted)) - (strtotime("now"))' should be '(strtotime("now")) - (strtotime($hm_datelisted))'. Next I was comparing the wrong number I should have done this first: 'strtotime("2 week") - strtotime("now")' to give me the number of 2 weeks. So I now have this: 'if((strtotime('now') - strtotime($hm_datelisted)) > (strtotime('2 week') - strtotime('now')))' which appears to do what I need. I will change to make it more elegant. Thank you for the outside view. It's always best to get an others perspective!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to display links that are older than 2 weeks? You can do that calculation in MySQL directly, saving yourself the considerable overhead of all those strtotime() calls in PHP:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE (yourdatefield + INTERVAL 2 WEEK) < now()
```